# need help determining what date format this is

Tags: date, date-format

I have a file that I'm going to be picking up nightly via SFTP.  The file has a naming convention that uses a date in the name.  Example `MyDbDump-2011-01-01_004324.sql.gz`

The part I don't understand is the last part `_004324`.  Any idea on how that is generated?  The host machine is a Red Hat box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a timestamp: 00h 43m 24s